# Drupal 7, how to push a div below the js files

Tags: javascript, html, drupal-7, hook

I need to push a div right above the end of the body tag, but there are allways scripts above it and i need it below of them
I already tried:

1. I tried to use Hook_page_build to push them but it allways comes above the js files.
2. I also tried page_alter
3. I gave it 999... weight to see if something happens but nothing
4. I also tryed to put it in a drupal_add_js(' .. '), but it is wrapping them with "".

Any ideas ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the template file https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7 and add the div there.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656 - generic documentation about templates

In your case, you might copy html.tpl.php to sites/all/themes/[yourtheme]/templates/ and to the modification there to have the div where you'd like.
If you use a sub-theme of the main theme, copy the html.tpl.php from your main theme, instead of Drupal core.

Answer (score 0):

drebabels has the same question on Drupal Answers https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/19132/48277

Kiamlaluno's answer explains how to achieve that using [hook_page_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19134/48277

However, his answer is working if your theme has a similar structure in html.tpl.php. Use it as an example.